# Main results vs ablation study in a journal paper (deep learning)

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I ran a number of experiments (object classification/segmentation), and got some good results vs a range of benchmark models. The paper progressed to major revision, and most criticism concerned the lack of ablation studied.

Essentially, what the reviewers want to see is the same experiments on the same data, but with a variation in the model's architecture (make it simpler, roughly speaking), in order to establish, that the more advanced architecture is in fact useful.

So, what happened, is that in some accuracy metrics simpler variations of the main model in fact outperformed it.

So here's my question: how can I incorporate this fact? One obvious solution is to point out that the main model still outperforms other in some metrics, but I have a feeling it's not enough.

What else can I say?

PS: this refers to the results, discussion and conclusion sections.

Comment: Do you have any justification why your initially chosen parameters should constitute the "main model" instead of the better ones found in the ablation study?

Comment: @GoodDeeds well, not really, I just came up with this arch. and it worked well. Technically I can replace the 'main' model with a simpler one, and then present the more involved ones in the ablation study, but first I'd like to know if I can use the current setup